# How do I tell my ViewController a View was touched?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am following through the Stanford iOS class and have a bit of a design question. In the class we are making a card matching game that has some 20 cards on screen or so. I recently made the cards UIViews so I could draw them properly.

I gave them each a method `tap` that will swap `faceUp` to YES/NO, thus flipping the cards. I add the gesture recognizer to each in my ViewController and it works. The individual cards know when they're touched and flip.

However, I need to know in my ViewController that a cardView has been touched... and which one.

How/what ways do I have to do this? Can I broadcast something in my View that the ViewController will listen for? Can I have my viewController handle that taps (but is there a way to get the sending view if I do this?) I apologize if this is really base, but I'm new to iOS and would like to not learn by patching and implementing a broken MVC pattern.

**EDIT: Just for information, this is my final implementation.**

Each CardView has a tap recognizer on it. When a tap is recognized it calls:

```
- (void)cardTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIView *view = [gesture view]; // This method is what I was looking for. 
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[PlayingCardView class]]) {
        PlayingCardView *playingCardView = (PlayingCardView *)view;
        [playingCardView flip];  // flips card
        // Game code
        if (!self.game.hasStarted) {
            [self startGame];
        }
        int cardIndex = [self.cardViews indexOfObject:playingCardView];
        [self.game chooseCardAtIndex:cardIndex];
        [self updateUI];
    }
}
```

Comment: If your are following the last course (dev IOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad), you should found the beginning of your answer in : Lecture 1 / Slide 22 (from view to VC, use Target Action !)

Comment: is the code that handle the flipping at the cardview level or the viewcontroller that contains your card?

Comment: The card will draw itself in its current state. So all that is required is to modify the faceUp variable. In my current implementation, my ViewController now identifies the tapped view, modifies faceUp and then proceeds to the necessary game code for a card tap.

Comment: FYI you should rather rely on the method attached to your gesture recognizer than the - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: @tiguero I was kind of wondering about that. It now seems I have a useless method. But touchesBegan has the information I need in it. Whereas I can't seem to get that information by being a method called by a gestureRecognizer. Also, this is working independently of a gesture recognizer. So maybe it makes more sense to just remove the gesture recognizer

Comment: You should read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html it will explain u why u should rely on the gesture recognizer vs the touchesBegan method on your controller

Comment: @tiguero Thank you for getting me to go back and look. It turns out that the gesture is able to tell me the view that sent it. That was all I needed. I have edited my final implementation and your answer is closer to what I did and your assistance got me there so the answer goes to you. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tag` property will tell you which view has been tapped. Set the proper tag when you create your view and in your action method that's been triggered on tap you can call a delegate method that will notify your delegate about which view has been tapped. Make your viewcontroller has the delegate and it will received the notification.

```
// your target method will look like this:
- (void) didTap:(id)sender {

   //... your code that handle flipping the card

   [self.delegate didTapOnCard:self]; // where delegate is your view controller

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use touchesBegan method to detect which view was tapped.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSLog(@"%d", [touch view].tag); // Considering you have set tags for your UIViews.. 

if([touch view] == cardView1) // Considering you have a view as cardView1
{
    NSLog(@"cardView1 is tapped");
}

}
```

Comment: This would go in my ViewController? That would be ideal if this is possible. I would then move my gesture recognizer to be my ViewController yes?

Comment: touches begin would also trigger if the use presses down on a view then drags off of it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `UIView` card class add

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)e {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([self pointInside:[touch locationInView:self] withEvent:nil]) {
        [self touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:e];
        // Add your card flipping code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast approach: in your UIView's `tap` method, send a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"cardTapped" object:self userInfo:@{ @"card": @(self.cardId), @"faceUp": @(self.faceup) }];
```

and in your ViewController subscribe to that notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(cardTapped:) name:@"cardTapped" object:nil];
```

and implement

```
-(void)cardTapped:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    int card = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"card"] intValue];
    BOOL faceUp = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"faceUp"] boolValue];
}
```

Comment: why not using delegation?

Comment: depends... I sometimes prefer the loose coupling that notifications provide, particularly when there is more than one receiver.

Comment: you should use notifications when you need to inform multiple objects of an event here only one object need to be notify: the view controller